# The reasoning behind why $7\mathbb{Z}_{28}$ is a summand of $\mathbb{Z}_{28}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

So, apparently it comes down to the fact that $7\mathbb{Z}_{28}+ 4\mathbb{Z}_{28}= \mathbb{Z}_{28}$. But, how should one know in that these two groups would work. I'm asking because the numbers could be changed and I want to know the general procedure for such questions.

Comment: Actually $3\Bbb Z_{28}=\Bbb Z_{28}$ already. Did you mean to say $7\Bbb Z_{28}+4\Bbb Z_{28}=\Bbb Z_{28}$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever $m$ and $n$ are positive integers with $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then
$$\Bbb Z_{mn}=m\Bbb Z_{mn}\oplus n\Bbb Z_{mn}.\tag{*}$$
This boils down to Bezout's identity; there are integers $a$ and $b$ with $am+bn=1$.
This implies $1\in m\Bbb Z_{mn}+ n\Bbb Z_{mn}$ and so
$\Bbb Z_{mn}= m\Bbb Z_{mn}+n\Bbb Z_{mn}$. But $|m\Bbb Z_{mn}|=n$ and $|n\Bbb Z_{mn}|=m$
so the sum is direct.